# К чему привязать asks

Tags: python

Пишу программу, где вопросы и ответы находятся не в программе, а в файле. Поэтому от прошлой версии остался asks, и программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
for qwestion, ar in asks.items():
NameError: name 'asks' is not defined
```

К чему надо привязать asks и как это написать?

Примеры вопросов из файла, если это нужно:

```
qwestion: Центральная часть атома; Какой газ является самым легким?; Какая формула у негашеной извести?; Почему срез яблока постепенно начинает желтеть?; Какие вещества нужно смешать, что бы получился порох?; 
answer: ядро; Водород; CaO; происходит процесс окисления содержащегося в яблоке железа; уголь, селитра, сера;
```

Вот код:

```
f = open('Вопросы.txt', 'r')
text = f.read()
print('Добро пожаловать на викторину!')
print('Правила просты: отвечаете правильно на вопрос - +1 бал, ответели неверно - 0')
score = 0
for qwestion, ar in asks.items():
    print(qwestion)
    answer = str(input("Ваш ответ: ").lower())
    if answer == ar:
        print('Правильный ответ!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Неправильный ответ!')
print('Вы набрали %s очка(-ов)' % score)
```

Comment: Видя код, можно предположить, что `asks` лежали уже распарсенные вопросы.

Comment: asks={"Вопрос":"Ответ"} раньше был в коде между score=0 и
for qwestion,ar in asks.items():
Однако мое задание требует, чтобы были вопросы и ответы в отдельной файле, там что теперь к чему привязать asks я не знаю(

Comment: Напишите парсер, вот и всё. Который в `asks` будет закидывать данные

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать, как это будет выглядеть? Я просто "немного" дно в программировании и знание команд

Comment: вы на каждый вопрос нового пользователя создаете? :D

Comment: Да(๑˃̵　ᴗ　˂̵)و Я бы сделала его спокойно и никого не тревожила, но преподаватели (зачем-то) перенести сдачу. А сдать сегодня надо, вот и пытаюсь крутиться как волчок и быстро все успеть сдать

Comment: Для начала прочитайте про функцию `split`, она вам поможет. Сначала отделить ключевое слово от данных по знаку `:`. А потом разделить данные уже по другому знаку `;`.

Comment: Знаете анекдот про математика, который на вопрос "как вскипятить полный чайник воды?" отвечает "выливаем воду из чайника и сводим задачу к предыдущей" вместо того, чтобы просто поставить чайник на плиту. Так и вы - пытаетесь свести к предыдущей задачу с совсем другими исходными данными. Вам не нужно к чему-то "привязывать asks" только из-за того, что в задаче с другими условиями так работало. Вам нужно решить задачу, где вопросы/ответы находятся в файле и разделены символом ``;``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил и дописал ваш код:

```
def parser(data):
    returns = {}

    requests, answers = data[0], data[1]

    requests = requests.replace(': ', ':').split(":")[1].split(";")[:-1]
    answers = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), answers.replace(': ', ':').split(":")[1].split(";")[:-1]))

    for requests, answer in zip(requests, answers):
        returns[requests] = answer.strip()

    return returns


f = open('Вопросы.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
text = f.readlines()
print('Добро пожаловать на викторину!')
print('Правила просты: отвечаете правильно на вопрос - +1 бал, ответели неверно - 0')

asks = parser(text)

score = 0
for question, answer in asks.items():
    print(question)
    if input("Ваш ответ: ") == answer:
        print('Правильный ответ!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Неправильный ответ!')

print(f'Вы набрали {score} очка(-ов)')
```

Comment: А вообще, нужно JSON использовать и не парсить вручную.

Comment: Не думала что парировать - это так много кода Спасибо огромное! (Но программа жалуется на asks = parser(text) и request, answers = data)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на викторину!
Правила просты: отвечаете правильно на вопрос - +1 бал, ответели неверно - 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pythonProject\main.py", line 13, in <module>
asks = parser(text)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in parser
requests, answers = data
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Покажите файл с вопросами. Там должно быть две строки.

Comment: Строка 1: qwestion:Центральная часть атома;Какой газ является самым легким?;Какая формула у негашеной извести?;Почему срез яблока постепенно начинает желтеть?;Какие вещества нужно смешать, что бы получился порох?;Как называется неделимая частица?;В какой воде меньше содержание примесей: дождевой, морской, минеральной?;Какой элемент используется при отбеливании белья?;Какой химический элемент стал причиной смерти Наполеона?;Какой химический элемент преобладает в составе каменного угля?.

Comment: Строка 2:answer:ядро;Водород;CaO;происходит процесс окисления содержащегося в яблоке железа;уголь, селитра, сера;атом;дождевой;хлор;мышьяк;Углерод.

Comment: Строка 1/2 в файле нет

Comment: Попробуйте тот код, что я предложил сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало! Конечно жаль, что нужно вводить именно так, как написано в файле (нельзя написать ЯДРО, нужно прописывать Ядро), но думаю я с этим справлюсь. Еще раз спасибо! 

Comment: У вас в коде был `.lower`, я его убрал. Но можно вернуть, если к обоим сравнениям добавить.